Changing the Color of a Set of Bars of a Clustered Column Chart
I have a clustered column chart where I'm looking at three (3) studies and the number of days it takes each of the 10 regions to perform the studies. I simply want to make all of Region 1 Green, Region 2 Red, etc. But when I change the bar color under the visualizations,it only changes the first instance of three. See below for my source data, PBI fields, attempt to change bar color, and output. Any help would be appreciated!





Have you placed Study1 in your legend?

You need to put your region into the legend part of the settings :

and then attribute a color to each of your columns :

And then choose your colors accordingly :

And if you need the labels, you can add them from the same place you chose the colors for your columns :

Hope this helps.

you can try to create a measure
Measure =
SWITCH ( MAX ( 'Table'[Region] ), "Region 1", 1, "Region 2", 2, "Region 3", 3 )

then do the settings



